# Object detection - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

**Issue in Tensorflow Object Detection model models**

From this installation guide : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

i started my installation

```
pip install --user Cython

pip install --user contextlib2

pip install --user pillow

pip install --user lxml

pip install --user jupyter

pip install --user matplotlib
```

COCO API installation:
copied - "**pycocotools**"  to **"/models/research/"**

From tensorflow/models/research/ i ran below command

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Added Libraries to PYTHONPATH (using Set since i am on windows)

```
set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Testing the Installation :

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

error :

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.

Download both 32 and 64 bits versions here: ([x86](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe), [x64](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)).

Cf. this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749